# SQL Server : executing Delete large number of queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have queries like below, which I have more than 50,000. When I start executing these queries all at once, it takes a long time.

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[WrongEntry] 
WHERE CompanyId=1 AND EmployeeId = 3 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 3 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' AND Entry_Method = 'I'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[WrongEntry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 4 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 4 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' AND Entry_Method = 'I'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[WrongEntry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 6 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 6 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' AND Entry_Method = 'I'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[WrongEntry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 7 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 7 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' AND Entry_Method = 'I'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[WrongEntry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 14 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'

DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 AND EmployeeId = 14 AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' AND Entry_Method = 'I'
```

I have not much hands on SQL Server, please guide me how to do this in some another way so that performance increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your sample queries, considering `CompanyId` and `Entry_Date` same for all the `EmployeeId's`

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[WrongEntry]
WHERE  CompanyId = 1
       AND EmployeeId in ( 3 ,4 , 6, 7, 14)
       AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'
```

For the above `Delete`, creating the below *Nonclustered* index could speed up the `delete`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_WrongEntry   
    ON  WrongEntry (CompanyId,EmployeeId,Entry_Date);
```

As per your sample queries, Considering `CompanyId`,`Entry_Method` and `Entry_Date` same for all the `EmployeeId's`

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Entry]
WHERE  CompanyId = 1
       AND EmployeeId in ( 3 ,4 , 6, 7, 14)
       AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'
       AND Entry_Method = 'I'
```

For the above `Delete`, creating the below *Nonclustered* index could speed up the `delete`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Entry   
    ON  Entry (CompanyId,EmployeeId,Entry_Date,Entry_Method);
```

If you can have different dates for each employee then add the values to temp table and join to delete the records just like Gordan's answer

Comment: I get all this queries from my mvc application code, so there is no scope of changing this queries.

Comment: @Anup - I dont know about `mvc` but if you want to improve then you have to change it. By the way do you have any index on both the tables ?

Comment: I have created index on Entry table on Entry_Date. where else should i create index. i have no knowledge of index, so please guide me on which type of index & on which columns.

Comment: @Anup - Updated give it a try. Note, without looking at the data we cannot suggest proper Index

Answer (score 1):

Limit the number of records to be deleted in a single transaction:

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT = 1

WHILE @RowCount > 0 BEGIN

DELETE TOP(500) FROM [dbo].[WrongEntry] 
WHERE CompanyId=1 AND EmployeeId IN (3 ,4 , 6, 7, 14) 
    AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'

SELECT @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

END

SELECT @RowCount = 1

WHILE @RowCount > 0 BEGIN

DELETE TOP(500) FROM [dbo].[Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId=1 AND EmployeeId IN (3 ,4 , 6, 7, 14)
    AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01'
    AND Entry_Method = 'I'

SELECT @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The deletes are very specific, I would look into creating an index to speed this function up.

Here is a free resource from a well renowned SQL Resource Guru that can help you identify missing indexes and what ones you should implement.

In addition, have you looked into partitioning the table depending on the version of your SQL Server? Partitioning based on the datestamp may drastically increase the performance of your SQL, but is a larger architectural change.

[SP_BlitzIndex](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/)

[Ozar on speeding up deletes](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/indexing-for-deletes/)

Answer (score 0):

Doing 50,000 deletes *is* going to take a bit of time.  One thing that might make them faster is an index on `(CompanyId, EmployeeId, Entry_Date)` in both tables.

A second thing would be to put the values for those columns into a temporary table and use a `join` for the deletion:

```
delete we
    from wrong_entry we join
         #todelete d
         on we.companyid = d.companyid and
            we.employeeid = d.employeeid and
            we.entry_date = d.entry_date;
```

You still want the indexes for this to be fast.  But, in addition, this puts all the deletes into the same transaction reducing the transactional overhead.

Actually, you could wrap your deletes in a transaction, and that might speed your code as well.